# How to specify output file encoding in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, ruby-1.9

How can I set the encoding of a file when using a `File#open`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's an example that outputs a file in the UTF-16LE encoding:

```
open("data.txt", "w:UTF-16LE")
```

Ruby looks at the encoding of the string you are writing, and transcodes as necessary. Here's a very detailed [blog post](http://graysoftinc.com/character-encodings/ruby-19s-three-default-encodings) describing mechanics with excellent examples (see the section called "The Default External and Internal Encodings").

Comment: It's odd that this feature is still undocumented on ruby-doc.org.

Answer (score 5):

That blog also has [a bunch of great information](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/understanding_m17n) about character encoding with Ruby, including [a post about encoding with Ruby 1.8](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_18_character_encoding_flaws).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to read pages with Japanese Shift JIS encoding:

```
  file = open(url, "r:Shift_JIS")
```