# Hebrew strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, hebrew

I am trying to create a text files with different sentences.
I am using File.stuff methods to do that.
How do I put a spacing (Simply like &nbsp in html and other lanuages)?
I've been told I should use \b . 
It doesn't seem to work - I belive it's because I am writing in hebrew.
What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what `File.stuff` is supposed to be - the File class has no such method.

If you want to use hebrew text in a ruby script, prepend the "magic encoding comment" to your file.

```
# encoding: UTF-8
hebrew = 'עברית'
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use that 'magic comment'.... Anyway- by file.stuff I meant I am using file methods (.write, .new etc.)

Comment: Exactly as I wrote - just put the "# encoding" comment at the top of your ruby script and it'll parse fine with foreign charsets. When reading a file through File, you also need to be aware of the encoding of that file. See this question: [How to specify output file encoding in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378185/how-to-specify-output-file-encoding-in-ruby)

Comment: In Ruby 2.0 and onwards, you can just use Hebrew literals in the source code.

Comment: @AsafBartov if its ruby 1.8.7 if I have hebrew text in strings, and added in `# encoding: UTF-8`, will it display properly? I also set utf-8 in html with meta charset in application.html.haml.