# How do I modify .sql files with ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby

I have a sql file (alice.sql) which looks like this in the editor

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dg_object_extern_pub_dg_extern_pub_status]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsForeignKey') = 1)ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dg_object_extern_pub] DROP CONSTRAINT FK_dg_object_extern_pub_dg_extern_pub_status GO
```

if I load that file into irb it looks like this

```
 f = File.open("alice.sql").readlines
```

it looks like this :(

```
=> ["\377\376i\000f\000 \000e\000x\000i\000s\000t\000s\000 \000(\000s\000e\000l\000e\000c\000t\000 \00
```

I wanted to search and replace some strings in the file but this seems impossible now

any ideas?

Comment: It's using UTF-16 or UCS-2 encoding.  Look up how localization and encodings work.

Comment: any resources? thanx in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378185/how-to-specify-output-file-encoding-in-ruby (is about output but the same things apply to input).

Comment: Thankyou, that's a great resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `f = File.open("alice.sql").readlines` you open a file handle, but never close it.

You should do:

```
f = File.open("alice.sql")
lines = f.readlines
f.close
```

or

```
File.open("alice.sql"){|f|
  lines = f.readlines
}
```

With `File#readlines` you get an array of lines. If you want to do replacements in a string, you shoudl use `read`instead:

```
File.open("alice.sql"){|f|
  content = f.read
}
```

And last, but not least: Your *alice.sql* seems to be UTF16, so you must read it as UTF-16:

```
File.open("alice.sql", :encoding => 'UTF-16BE:UTF-8'){|f|
  content = f.read
}
```

Now you get `\uFEFFif exists (sele...` You see the leading BOM?
To get rid of it, use:

```
File.open("alice.sql", :encoding => 'BOM|UTF-16BE:UTF-8'){|f|
  content = f.read
}
```

(Needs ruby 1.9, maybe the BOM-version requires 1.9.3).

If you need the content outside the block, the variable must be defined outside the block (or you use File#close)

```
content = nil #define variable, so you get the content after the open-block
File.open("alice.sql", :encoding => 'BOM|UTF-16BE:UTF-8'){|f|
  content = f.read
}
p content
```

Comment: looks funny...seems to be not UTF-16
\uFFFE椀昀 攀砀椀猀琀猀

Comment: Can you try `UTF-16LE`? I haven't checked, if you have big or little endian.