# How to open .sql file with ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby

```
 f = File.open("alice.sql").readlines
```

but I think I need some kind of SQL-Library and RubyGem to be able to work and manipulate the file.

Any libraries that would do the job?

Comment: What is it that you intend to do with the SQL file? Manipulate the statements in it? Execute it?

Comment: Do you need to manipulate the sql-file, or do you want to execute it on your DB?

Comment: I want to search for some strings e.g. '[bdo]' and want to replace them with ['bdo_dc']

I think this could be done very easily in ruby, if I could treat it as a .txt file

Comment: An *.sql file **is** a text file. You could not even mention SQL in this question.

Comment: but how do I deal with the encoding? It is not a plain text file. Ruby thinks it is UTF-8 
f.external_encoding.name
but it is a format like ["\377\376i\000f\000 \000e\000x\000i
and there is no way to know, which character encoding that is

Comment: Can't you set the encoding to UTF-8 before you save the file?

Comment: What's the difference to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573718/how-do-i-modify-sql-files-with-ruby ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute it, you can use [ActiveRecord](http://www.rabbitcreative.com/2007/06/08/executing-raw-sql-in-rails) or [DataMapper](http://www.mail-archive.com/datamapper@googlegroups.com/msg00759.html) for example.

Comment: thanx, but I do not want to execute it. I just want to treat it as a text file, which I can alter and then I want to create a new .sql file